# Domain direction problems

Tags: html, css, dns, redirect

I've learnt HTML and CSS from Codecademy the past two months and am sitting with 4 HTML-documents and 4 CSS-files right now ready to connect them to the Internet. 
I've bought a domain, registered a webhotel and downloaded FileZilla for transferring the files. My problem is that instead of being directed to the website, I'm directed to a page that contains the headline "Index /" and the name of the folder which contains my files.

How do I fix this? I have a feeling that I have to do something with my homepage.html so that the domain directs me to that specific page.

Comment: rename to `index.html` ;-) You can of course over-ride the `DirectoryIndex` page. But the easiest way would just be to rename your homepage file.

Answer (score 0):

if you sure domain connected to your webhost successfully,just upload your website to htdocs folder and rename your first page to `index.html` **note** : all the character should be lowercase

Comment: You can not believe what just happened... I was just about to drag my websitefolder from the left bar to the right in Filezilla, and I accidentally doubleclicked the left mousebutton and now it says that it deleted my folder!!! Anyone who knows how to restore the files? :/

Comment: You can't hard delete with Filezilla, it would have prompted you, "Are you sure you want to delete"...If you're connected to a remote ftp, and double click, then it will upload the file.

Comment: Are you sure? Becuase I've searched my whole computer since and the folder's nowhere to be found.. In my log it said that it successfully deleted every file in the folder...

Comment: Which log? You mean the one at the top of Filezilla? that would say something like Command: `DELE work.part2.rar Response: 250 Deleted work.part2.rar` ?

Comment: Yeah that's the one! What do I do?

Comment: For instance it said "Commando: DELE hompage.html". There were a commando: DELE for every file in the folder. It's just weird that Filezilla could delete files like that without, as you said, prompting me!

Comment: It *should* just send them to the Recycle bin, but not actually delete them.

Comment: It didn't :/ It's amazing how an FTP-client is just allowed to delete files like that. At the moment I'm searching my whole computer for deleted files with FileScavenger... In the worst case scenario I'll just have to tell my teacher about the whole thing and create an easy website online and then point out that I know how the codes work (my assignment was to learn the codes necessary for the website and then create it, and I know both HTML and CSS now so I'll try to meet the teacher halfway by explaining the codes of the easy website)

Comment: Wait, you mentioned `I'm directed to a page that contains the headline "Index /" and the name of the folder which contains my files.` - so you actually have the folder on the ftp then?

Comment: I did have it there, then I wanted to change my homepage.html to index.html, which I did on my computer. So I deleted it from the server in order to put in the new version but it was deleted before transferring..

Answer (score 0):

Well guys I solved the problem I encountered when accidentely "deleting" my files from FileZilla. Apparently my computer immediately downloaded the file folder when FileZilla deleted it so it was in "Downloaded Files" (don't know what the folder's called in English, I'm Swedish) all along.

Regarding my initial question I just want to thank you guys for helping me with the right answer! It's working correct now :)